# Call Signature vs Function Type Expression when describing an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

In the typescript docs for [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) it states that:

> In JavaScript, functions can have properties in addition to being callable. However, the function type expression syntax doesn’t allow for declaring properties. If we want to describe something callable with properties, we can write a call signature in an object type

The docs then give the following example:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
 
function myFunc(someArg: number) {
  return someArg > 3;
}
myFunc.description = "default description";
 
doSomething(myFunc);
```

Now functions are indeed objects, callable objects and the above example describes a callable object with a declared `description` property.

Do call signatures refer to describing function objects only, and if not, is there a difference between describing an object with a call signature vs a function type expression as shown below?

```
interface User {
  id: number,
  greet: (name: string) => string
}

interface User {
  id: number,
  greet(name: string): string
}
```

Comment: `{ greet(name: string): string }` isn't what I'd describe as "call signature" syntax; I'd say it's "method" syntax. An object with a call signature is callable itself, while an object with a method has a callable method.  If you can write `f()` then `f` has a call signature (although the *syntax* used to describe it could be different).  But `f.m()` implies that `f.m` has a call signature, not `f`.  So yes, "call signatures refer to describing function objects only".  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something about what you're asking?

Comment: Yes that is an important piece I needed to know, and there is literally no information about this anywhere online. Is there any difference you can think of then in the last code block? I see this in the vue docs and it confuses me why we have a "method" syntax sometimes then other times a function type expression

Comment: That's a followup question, right? It has a different answer and thus is out of scope.  You can find answers to that in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887751/2887218).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I couldn't find

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer to your primary question when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology is a sometimes a bit fuzzy, but generally speaking a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) is a member of a *callable* object type.  If the object is not itself callable, then it does not have a call signature.  So

```
interface Greet {
  (name: string): string
}
```

has a call signature, an object of type `Greet` is callable:

```
interface Greet {
  (name: string): string
}
declare const greet: Greet;
greet("abc"); // okay
```

But

```
interface User {
  id: number,
  greet(name: string): string
}
```

does not have a call signature, since an object of type `User` is *not* callable:

```
declare const user: User;
user("abc"); // error!
```

Instead it has a `greet` *method*.  That method is callable:

```
user.greet("abc"); // okay
```

so you could say that the `greet` method has a call signature, although if you inspect that type it will be displayed as a [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions):

```
type G = User["greet"];
// type G = (name: string) => string
```

But the difference between call signature syntax and function type expression syntax is mostly out of scope here. There are other questions, like [Difference between arrow function vs normal function inside interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54884489/2887218), that cover that.  For our purposes they are essentially the same; you'd have a similar experience with this definition of `User`:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  greet: Greet;
}
declare const user: User;
user.greet("abc"); // okay
type G = User["greet"];
// type G = Greet;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQhMyDeBYAKGWQAoQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzASloaZGcIF9CAJhAQAbOBmQIA9iAbJmGLLXSYwAbkILVJAERwARgh2s1yAPRnkUgNZwAnoUKhIsRCgCqdaLkLFgA2hAAVwp9aAAaX3lFMDJKGnpGFnZErh4CfgIhUXEUaVlsIK8oWk9oDQIi6F0DIxNzS2goKSgAQkIqqAA6LSwaw2NTCytbBwJCMDsABxRUZABeZDKoAG0dXrAdAF0K4cmZtAXScioOJO5WBYA+VJZHAmdoeCQl4oAmHyJkf0CQsKgKsQNsoYhVMtkxBJ8nJOm9SsUKrCejF+nUhpYbPZCEA)

Comment: Thank you! The typescript docs are very lacking on a few topics, this is much more specific.