# TS - class method is undefined in callback

Tags: typescript, class, scope, callback

I think that code is worth a thousand words. Take this example

```
class Cat {

 constructor() {
  this.meow("roar", this.sound)
 }

 meow(a, callback) {
  callback(a)
 }

 sound(a) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(this.sayMeow) <----- THIS IS UNDEFINED
 }

 sayMeow() {
  return "Meow"
 }
}
```

As you can see method `sayMeow()` is undefined. Can you please explain why and how can i solve it?

**This is just simplified representation of more complex code where i have to use callbacks. I need to know why method is undefined inside callback function. Please do not write modifications of this simple Cat class.**

Thank you

Comment: In javascript, `this` is determined by how a function is called, rather than where it is defined. Since you pass `this.sound` to another function as a callback, when it's called, it will reference a different `this` than what you expect. You may be interested in this question: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

In JavaScript, the `this` is determined when a function is called. In your case, `sound(a)` is called with the `this` context of `undefined`.

if you insist on using `this` inside `sound(a)`, there are two common solutions:

- use a class property function (an *arrow function*) instead of a method
- bind the `this` context in the constructor

The first approach was popularized by React, and it worked fine because user-created React components are meant to be final classes. However, if you are doing object-oriented programming and you expect your `Cat` class to be inherited from, you cannot use this approach for [it breaks inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997455/10325032).

**Solution**

Bind the context of execution to the instance of your class in the constructor.

```
class Cat {
    constructor() {
        this.sound = this.sound.bind(this)
        this.meow("roar", this.sound)
    }

    meow(a, callback) {
        callback(a)
    }

    sound(a) {
        console.log(a)
        console.log(this.sayMeow)
    }

    sayMeow() {
        return "Meow"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because of Javascript this context when passing **this**.
When passing **this** you should always bind it to the current context

The **this** keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called. With arrow functions however, this is lexically bound. It means that it uses **this** from the code that contains the arrow function.

*Arrow function:*

```
() => {}
```

Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context.

```
class Cat {

 constructor() {
  this.meow("roar", this.sound)
 }

 meow(a, callback) {
  callback(a)
 }

 sound = (a) => {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(this.sayMeow)
 }

 sayMeow() {
  return "Meow"
 }
}
```

Comment: This approach is safe only when `Cat` is not inherited from. If it is, there will be [a runtime error](https://links.wtf/4rvl).

Comment: This worked as advertised.  Not planning on using inheritance with my solution and could not get @Karol Majewski's binding trick to work as the method is being called back from a different class.